# Python - workaround with sets

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to write a code with sets which takes in the binary value of a number and adds 0's in front of the binary value such that the total number of digits are 10.
for ex -

```
Binary value of 27 is 11011.
so the output should be 0000011011.
In sets it should give me {1,1,0,1,1} and {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1}
```

But as sets discard any duplicate so i am not able to store or add any duplicate elements. Is there any workaround for this? I cant use lists.

Comment: Why not just use `str.ljust()` or `format()` to format your number as a padded binary representation? Sets are definitely the wrong approach here.

Comment: Sets do not preserve order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use `format` and `zfill`

```
n = 27
print "{0:b}".format(n).zfill(10) # prints "0000011010"
```

You can also accomplish this with just a single `format` (although it's a little harder to read)

```
n = 27
print "{0:010b}".format(n) # prints "0000011010"
```